C# + Selenium + Chrome DevTools Protocol: how to capture traffic from new tab
I'm trying to build a network traffic monitor to log requests/responses within the Chrome browser. I use Selenium and its API for working with the Chrome DevTools Protocol. So something like that works fine:
var devTools = (IDevTools)driver;
var devToolsSession = devTools.GetDevToolsSession(130);
devToolsSession.DevToolsEventReceived += OnDevToolsEventReceived;
devToolsSession.Domains.Network.EnableNetwork().Wait();

I'm getting network info indeed. But if a click on some point opens URL in a new tab, traffic from that new tab won't be captured. I found a lot of articles on the web regarding the case, but nothing helps.
OK, I understand that dev tools session is attached to a window, and new tab is in fact a window too. But I don't understand how to create a new dev tools session just before any traffic will go within a new tab. I'm able to create a session attached to the tab, but request which loads a webpage will be missed (since all my manipulations with new detools session take some ms of time).
Is there a guide how to solve the task?

You can ask new target to wait until debugger is attached, setup your network domain and the resume the target. https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/#method-setAutoAttach

I've tried different combinations of what you're talking about and nothing works. Can you please write an answer with exact steps?
